# The same value is assigned to different elements of an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

It is the first time I am writing of stackoverflow and I have the following question:
I have an array named "components", whose elements are objects. Every object has different properties, but when I assign a value to a given property to components[0], the same value is assigned to components[1]. I tried different ways to fix this issue, but to no avail. Here is the code:

```html
  function update(x)
  {
  component = Number(x.id.split("_")[1]) - 1;
  property = x.id.split("_")[0];
  value = Number(x.value);
  components[component][property] = value;
  return
  }
```

For example, in the following HTML code:

```
   <tr>
        <th>
            Viscosity at 50 &deg;C (cSt)
        </th>
        <td>
            <center>
            <input type="text" 
              onchange="update(this);" 
              class="property" 
              id="viscosity_1">
            </center>
        </td>
        <td class="last" >
            <center>
            <input type="text" 
              onchange="update(this);" 
              class="property" 
              id="viscosity_2">
            </center>
        </td>
   </tr>
```

when the user assign the property "viscosity_1", the js function divides the id string in "viscosity" and "1", and should assign the value inserted by the user to components[0].viscosity , leaving components[1].viscosity unaffected. Actually, if either "viscosity_1" and "viscosity_2" are changed by the user, both components[0].viscosity and components[1].viscosity are updated.

Comment: I just checked. Your code works fine

Comment: Is there some more JS code? Where do you define the `components` array? Could you please extend the JS snippet with all the necessary variables?

Answer (score 0):

Some more details: in the js code, the components array had been defined as such:

```
var ncomp = 2; 
var components = Array(ncomp).fill({});
```

The components array has been initialized by the function initialize(), which is executed when the page is loaded:

```html
function initialize()
  {
  inputList = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("property"));
  var len = inputList.length;
  var property
  var index
  for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
    property = inputList[i].id.split("_")[0];
    index = Number(inputList[i].id.split("_")[1]) - 1;
    components[index][property] = NaN;
    }
  return
  }
```